# Can I use regex with page contain that get from ajax() function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, regex

I want to get contain from marquee tag in some page.
This is my code

```
var myurl = "http://www.somewhere.com/somepage.html";
var patt = /.+<marquee.+>(.+)<\/marquee>.+/;

$.ajax({
    url: myurl,
    success: function(data){
        var r = patt.exec(data);
        console.debug(r[1]);
    },
});
```

I found that, variable r is null.
What is my mistake ?

PS. I do a chrome extension, so it allows me to call ajax() in other domain.

Comment: why don't get url from jquery selctor

Comment: Do you have an example or reference link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reasons for not parsing HTML with regular expressions that I'm not going to go into here.

In your case, I suspect that there may be newlines within the `<marquee>` tag which your regex can't match.

Try

```
/<marquee[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/marquee>/
```

and see what happens.

`[\s\S]` matches any character (whitespace or non-whitespace, a kludge to compensate for JavaScripts lack of a "dot matches all" mode), `*?` allows the match to occur any number of times, but as few as possible so we don't match across multiple `<marquee>` tags.

Comment: [\s\S] works! Like you answer. Marquee content in mult-lines can't match with "dot matches all". This is my work patt -> /<marquee.+>([\s\S]*)<\/marquee>/

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off extracting the text using jQuery element constructors rather than string manipulation. It's more reliable and easier to read:

```
var r = $('<div>' + data + '</div>').find('marquee').html();
```

The wrapping div is there to ensure jQuery treats the data as HTML elements, and not a selector string.

Comment: Thanks for response. I try your solution but it errors when I wrap my data with <div> in $. About my data is start with <DOCTYPE> and end with </html>

Comment: @diewland ah I didn't realise it was a full page. You don't need the wrapping div if the string starts and ends with an element.

Comment: Wow! I get your idea. Thanks.