# jQuery - getting the contents of the body of an Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

This function is my ASP.NET MVC Ajax error handler. I want to get the response HTML and add it to a div, but only what's inside the body. If I embed the straight response, it ends up merging the html and body tags of the error page response with the current page, resulting in messed up text sizes. How can I get JUST the contents of the body? I tried `$('body', resp).html()` but that doesn't give me anything.

```
function crayzeAjaxError(request) {
    var resp = request.response;
    if ($('#crayze-ajax-error-dialog').size() == 0) {
        $('body').append('<div id="crayze-ajax-error-dialog" title="AJAX error" style="display:none;">' +
            '<p>Sorry, the request failed with status code ' + request.status + '</p>' +
            '<button id="crayze-ajax-error-dialog-show-details">Show details</button>' +
            '<object id="crayze-ajax-error-dialog-response"></object>' +
            '</div>');
    }

    $('#crayze-ajax-error-dialog-response').hide();

    $('#crayze-ajax-error-dialog').dialog({ width: 600, height: 400, modal: true });

    $('#crayze-ajax-error-dialog-show-details').click(function () {
        $('#crayze-ajax-error-dialog-response').html($('body', resp).html());
        $('#crayze-ajax-error-dialog-response').show();
    });
}
```

Comment: var bodyText= $(responce).find('body').html(); try this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work:

```
$(resp).find('> *').appendTo($('div#xxx'));
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
$('body', $(resp)).html()
```

I did what you want with this piece of code. Hope it helps.

```
var regexp = /<body[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/body>/;
var mbody = regexp.exec(resp);
```

I found this answer in [Can I use regex with page contain that get from ajax() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873162/can-i-use-regex-with-page-contain-that-get-from-ajax-function)

Comment: You are right. I tought it would work because i did it but not with a entire page. Now i think the only way is using Regualr Expression. Now, i did this <body\b[^>]*>(.*?)</body> and it work. Try it here http://regexpal.com/ and check "dot matches all".